# Adding AppCentre Pod to xCode project gives import modules error

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-app-center

I wish to integrate AppCenter into an existing iOS ObjectiveC xCode project.

I have followed the instructions in the AppCenter project portal to add the AppCenter pod to my project:

[image]

I see that the AppCenter pod has been successfully installed but when I try to import itin my project like so I get an error "Use of import when modules are disabled"

[image]

How can I add this  pod to my project successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select your project -> `Build Settings` -> `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` switch to `YES`